# Get confidence interval from emmeans contrast function

Tags: r, emmeans

I am looking to get a confidence interval from the `contrast` function from the `emmeans` package.

Taking an example model:

```r
model <- lm(mpg ~ factor(cyl) + hp, data = mtcars)

emmeans(model, specs = ~ cyl) %>%
  contrast()
```

gives:

```
 contrast    estimate    SE df t.ratio p.value
 cyl4 effect     4.83 1.168 28   4.134  0.0009
 cyl6 effect    -1.14 0.931 28  -1.223  0.2315
 cyl8 effect    -3.69 1.332 28  -2.772  0.0147

P value adjustment: fdr method for 3 tests
```

I can calculate a confidence interval manually using the mean and standard error, but I was wondering: is there is a parameter I can change to output this automatically? I can do a manual version like so:

```r
emmeans(model, specs = ~ cyl) %>%
  contrast() %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  mutate(lcl = estimate + qnorm(0.025) * SE,
         ucl = estimate + qnorm(0.975) * SE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the results to `confint()`:

```r
library(emmeans)
emmeans(model, specs = ~ cyl) |> contrast() |> confint()
```

Results:

```
 contrast    estimate    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 cyl4 effect     4.83 1.168 28     1.85     7.80
 cyl6 effect    -1.14 0.931 28    -3.51     1.23
 cyl8 effect    -3.69 1.332 28    -7.08    -0.30

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Conf-level adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 estimates
```

Note that this uses multiple-comparisons correction (as noted in the output). `confint(adjust="none")` gets answers closer to your manual solution, although it uses `qt(., df = 28)` rather than `qnorm(.)` to compute the ranges.